# Jest spy the external function issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

For some reasone I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot spy the handleError property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

I'm using spy method...

```
const spyHandleError = jest.spyOn(handleError, 'handleError');
```

...to check if the handleError function was called:

```
expect(spyHandleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

My handleError function looks like that:

```
import { reduxAction } from '../store/actions/auth';

export const handleError = (status, dispatch) => {
  if(status === 403) {
    return dispatch(reduxAction());
  }
};
```

Why I'm getting this error and how can I use spyOn method to test that?

Comment: Could you provide the complete test case? That would help to understand what you want to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the *jest.spyOn* method you have to provide as first argument the object that contains the method you want to spy ([documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)).

You are probably importing the *handleError* method like:

```
import { handleError } from 'file-where-handle-error-is';
```

Therefore, your imported *handleError* is directly the function and not an object that contains the function.

To solve your problem you can import the module where *handleError* is located and then mock the *handleError* method:

```
const utils = require('file-where-handle-error-is');
const spyHandleError = jest.spyOn(utils, 'handleError');
```

Another solution would be to mock the module where *handleError* is located with jest.mock:

```
jest.mock('../../../src/utils/handle-error', () => {
return {
    handleError: jest.fn()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to spy on a function that is exported from a file that contains many other functions (such as a helper file), then you can import all functions as an object like so:

```
import * as errorHelpers from 'path/to/errorHelpers';
```

Then you can set up your spy as follows:

```
const spyHandleError = jest.spyOn(errorHelpers, 'handleError');
```